# wpf data grid create dynamically

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net, winforms, wpf-controls

I am new to WPF control. I need the output as below attached image. The Below code is the output for WPF Grid. I would like to repeat the grid header for n no.of. times.  based on the date range selected by the user. 
Any one please advise me how to achieve this dynamically

```
    <Grid Grid.Row="3">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Border Grid.Column="0">
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="P2L3" TextAlignment="Center" />
        </Border>
        <Border Grid.Column="1">
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="P1L2" TextAlignment="Center" />
        </Border>
        <Border Grid.Column="2">
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="P2L3" TextAlignment="Center" />
        </Border>
        <Border Grid.Column="3">
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="P1L2" TextAlignment="Center" />
        </Border>
    </Grid>
    <Grid Grid.Row="4">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions >
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Border Grid.Column="0">
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="GEN3" TextAlignment="Center" />
        </Border>
        <Border Grid.Column="1">
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="GEN3" TextAlignment="Center" />
        </Border>
        <Border Grid.Column="2">
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="GEN3" TextAlignment="Center" />
        </Border>
        <Border Grid.Column="3">
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="GEN3" TextAlignment="Center" />
       </Border>          
    </Grid>

</Grid>
```

[image]

> Can any advise me to write it dynamically and the output will repeat for n times using code.
>   i.e the same header is changed by date.
>   My Final out put will be as below
>   [image]

Comment: C# or VB.Net? - It might be important to note that your code sample does not contain the code that creates every row

Comment: check itemscontrol and datatemplate

Comment: This looks like a `TreeView` to me. See [this CodeProject post](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17025/Custom-TreeView-Layout-in-WPF).